# Reading custom stanzas in converseJS plugin?

Tags: javascript, converse.js

Is it possible to receive custom stanzas in converse.js?

I tried to `listen` to incoming messages:

```
converse.plugins.add('dummy', {
  initialize: function() {
    var _converse = this._converse;

    _converse.api.listen.on('message', function(xmlMessage) {
      console.log('Received message!');
    });
  }
});
```

My custom stanza looks like this:

```
<message to='...' from='...' type='groupchat'>
    <custom_stanza>
        <created_at>2018-02-14T16:25:00+01:00</created_at>
        <store xmlns='urn:xmpp:hints'/>
    </custom_stanza>
</message>
```

But unfortunately this stanza won't get recognized here. Normal messages work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why a `message` event isn't triggered for your custom message. There must be some assumption in the converse.js code which your custom message doesn't fulfill.

Converse.js uses [Strophe.js](http://strophe.im/) under the hood, so you can use Strophe's [addHandler](http://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.2.14/files/strophe-js.html#Strophe.Connection.addHandler) to register an event handler on a lower level.

Here's how you would do this:

```
converse.plugins.add('dummy', {
  initialize: function() {
    var _converse = this._converse;

    _converse.on('connected', () => {

      // _converse.connection is an instance of Strophe.Connection
      // which provides the `addHandler` method.

      _converse.connection.addHandler((message) => {
         // Your message handling code comes here...

      }, null, 'message');
   });
  }
});
```

An example of this usecase is in the [converse-bookmarks.js](https://github.com/jcbrand/converse.js/blob/5517e3554cc1acee23d3e0934ab649110b4135a7/src/converse-bookmarks.js#L569) plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I implemented a new handler with Strophe's addHandler - and now I am able to read custom stanzas. Unfortunately this does not work for archived messages. How can I read archived custom stanzas?

Comment: The same way, just make sure what you're registering your handler correctly. Read the Strophe.js API documentation for `addHandler` which I linked to in my answer.